# How long are kubernetes logs stored?

Tags: kubernetes

If I run, for example, `kubectl logs --namespace kube-system kube-apiserver-XXXX | head -n 25` I can see the output with only a timestamp and no date. I can't tell if these are from the inception of the pod or not.

Generally speaking, how long do a pod's logs last in Kubernetes?

Comment: Pod logs are cut at midnight. Look into ES+Kibana for a good log aggregation solution. Or Sumologic for a paid hosted solution

Comment: _Pod logs are cut at midnight._ do you have a citation for that, because it's 100% for sure not the case in my cluster. I believe the logs are as available as they are configured to be by docker on the Node, which in our case is [json-file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/json-file/#usage), 3 file limit, 100MB per file, causing quiet containers to appear infinite, chatty ones have less retention

Comment: Separately: yes, you will be much happier if you egress logs into ES. We currently use [logspout-redis-logstash](https://github.com/rtoma/logspout-redis-logstash) to egress _all_ container logs, freeing the app from having to worry about such things. I also just saw [logspout-redis-multiline](https://github.com/briankohler/logspout-redis-multiline) which looks even better

Answer (score 6):

[From k8s unofficial docs](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#:%7E:text=Kubernetes%20performs%20log%20rotation%20daily,five%20logging%20rotations%20per%20container.)

> Kubernetes performs log rotation daily, or if the log file grows beyond 10MB in size. Each rotation belongs to a single container; if the container repeatedly fails or the pod is evicted, all previous rotations for the container are lost. By default, Kubernetes keeps up to five logging rotations per container.

The container runtime attaches the current timestamp to every line produced by the application. You can display these timestamps by using the --timestamps=true option while running kubectl logs.

Comment: Maybe this information is outdated. Because in my experience k8s does not perform log rotation *at all* (I'm currently running a cluster at Linode). Logs are kept forever, so if I use the command `kubectl logs <podID>` I get a log that reaches back to the creation of the pod. Here is a related question on serverfault that seems to confirm this: [How long kubernetes stores pod stdout logs?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1018783/how-long-kubernetes-stores-pod-stdout-logs). Fortunately, the answer includes some proposals how to change the default behavior of keeping logs forever...

Comment: @robert This may vary from one distribution of K8s to another. In case of Azure AKS, I can confirm that the logs are purged. The amount (size) of the logs matter here. If your application is not writing a lot of logs then k8s might preserve the logs from the moment the pod was created.  I'm assuming you are using some kind of managed K8s on Linode which should take care of log rotate, archive and purge for you. If it doesn't then there is a risk of node disk space getting fully used up by the logs.